# Why did Obito's left hand get detached in this scene?

Tags: naruto

[image: Naruto Shippuden episode 248]

Why did Obito left hand got melted and detached.. wasn't his right hand made of zetsu.. his left hand was not crushed under the rock.

This is from episode 248.

Comment: I think it's a mistake made during the anime production

Answer (score -1):

So you mean this scene?
[image]

Well, the way that you're looking at it Obito's right arm was squished, but the truth is that his left arm is squished, it's just the way you're looking at it. :)

Comment: Can you explain how is his left arm squished?

Comment: @LOL if left arm was squished so should be his left eye. I don't think your answer is valid